# getting slider value from past

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm having a page jquery slider and page gets refreshed by on submit. How to keep the past value of a slider after refreshing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either save it on the server, pass it as a value in the query string, or save value to a cookie - these are the only ways to persist data between pages.